# Reuse ORM tables across databases

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have an applicaiton that manages several SQLite databases. I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy for the ORM mapping, because I'm trying
to not duplicate the table definitions. However, I want some tables to be present in several databases.

```py
class Mixin(MappedAsDataclass):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, init=False, repr=False)
    
    @classmethod
    def __table_cls__(cls, table_name: str, metadata_obj: MetaData, *arg, **kwargs):
        return Table(table_name, metadata_obj, *arg, **kwargs)


class Address(Mixin):
    street: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    house_number: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
    coordinates: Mapped[List[float]] = mapped_column(ListOfFloats)


class Account(Mixin):
    account_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    balance: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float)


class User(Mixin):
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    birthdate: Mapped[dt.datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime)
    interests: Mapped[List[str]] = mapped_column(ListOfStrings)
    address_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('address.id'), init=False)
    address: Mapped[Address] = relationship(Address, foreign_keys=['address_id'], cascade='all, delete')
    account_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'), init=False, nullable=True)
    account: Mapped[Account] = relationship(Account, foreign_keys=['account_id'], cascade='all, delete')
```

Here, I want to for example have a database (let's call it the `AccountDatabase`) with only the `Account` table, and another
database (`UserDatabase`) that has all three tables.

I'm creating a "database" object for each which should take care of the mapping and such:

```py
class AccountDatabase:
    def __init__(self, path: str, creator: Callable=None):
        self.engine = self.create_engine(path, creator)
        mapper_registry = registry()
        mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Account, Account.__table_cls__('account', mapper_registry.metadata))
        mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

    @staticmethod
    def create_engine(path: str, creator: Callable=None):
        """Returns a default SQLAlchemy engine for sqlite if no creator is supplied."""
        engine = create_engine(f'sqlite+pysqlite:///{path}')
        if creator is not None:
            engine = create_engine(f'sqlite+pysqlite:///{path}', creator=creator)
        return engine
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper[Account(account)] could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'account'
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do in SQLAlchemy 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use one database with **multiple schema**. You can find more information here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html. In this case you can create **metadata** to manage **multiple ORM classes** **using inheritance** or you can specify **table args** like this:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sometable"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "some_schema"}
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html

Comment: One of the points is that I want to have multiple sets of sqlite database files for the different sets of tables. But I guess that might not be possible then? Because, if I set `{"schema": "account_database"}` on the `Account` table, I won't be able to reuse it with `{"schema": "user_table"}` or did I misunderstand?